# Breaking string into a sequence of substrings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split any string into a list of 3-character substrings.

For example: `abcdefgh` splits into:

```
abc , bcd , cde , def , efg , fgh
```

So I wrote the following regex :

```
"abcd".match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

but it outputs as `abc , d`. How could I achieve the output as described above?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The linked duplicate wants a string split every 3 characters. 'abcdefgh' => 'abc , bcd , cde , def , efg , fgh' is not splitting every 3 characters

Answer (score 0):

Since there can not be overlapping matches, you need to use *something* that prohibits regex engine from advancing and consuming the string.

The answer is lookarounds, specifically: positive lookahead. It won't consume string and can have captuirng group inside, which you can then access.

Use this pattern: `(?=([a-z]{3}))`. It asserts, that what follows current position are three lowercase letters. Since it's wrapped in lookahead, it won't advance *behind* found three letters.

In result, you will get 6 matches, which will be empty, **but** each match will contain **capturing group**, which will contain three letters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AO6jPc/1)